# Best Way To Install An Additional Outlet Near Sink?

Tags: electrical, bathroom, gfci

I am replacing an old built in vanity with a drop-in replacement. The replacement has built in outlets on one side. As you can see in the picture, the vanity has a hole to pass the cord through on the back side, but my plan was to drill a new hole in the side of the vanity and place an outlet directly on the other side of the hole so I can push the vanity right up against the corner and not strain the plug.

[image]

I cut away some drywall to take a look and I have easy access to pigtail off of an outlet whose receptacle is on the other side of the wall. Since this is not a GFCI outlet, I would have to figure a way to make the new outlet GFCI protected (could I just add a GFCI receptacle and call it good?). The alternative would be to pigtail off the existing GFCI protected bathroom outlet, but I would have to cut more drywall which I would like to avoid if possible.

[image]

Is it even safe to have any outlet in this position given the sink in close proximity? I would imagine that the manufacturer of this vanity wouldn't be selling it with outlets in this position if it wasn't safe but I'm not sure. I'm in the United States for code compliance.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You certainly can just install a GFCI receptacle. However, you will need to mount the new box securely to something (perhaps added 2x4 blocking?). You will also need to identify all the outlets on the circuit you want to use, what gauge wiring is in place and what size circuit breaker controls it, so you can determine if the wiring can support your new receptacle. It could very well draw a lot of current if you've got something like a blow dryer plugged in, and it looks like there is something else downstream of the other-room-outlet you want to tap into.

Comment: You will also need to make the hole/window in your vanity large enough to expose the whole outlet faceplate, so it can be removed and the box accessed in the future if repairs/changes are needed.

Comment: are there any code labels on it